# Windows Update blue screen in a different language

Tags: windows-10, updates, language

My computer has two language packs installed. One is english and the other one.

It was originally in the other language but I have configured to use english by default.
(In the control panel -> language )

However I turn off the computer and the "Dont turn off the computer" screen appears (for the windows update) the language is the other language.

How can I configure that that message is in english too?

Edit:
I found [this resource](https://blog.techinline.com/2016/03/29/how-to-change-the-language-of-welcome-screen-in-windows-10/) and it seems useful. However the menu in control panel does not appear in some versions of Windows 10

Comment: Have you considered removing the language pack that isn’t being used?

Comment: yes but unfortunatelly that is not an option i can take

Comment: I assume it’s because your not the Administrator?

Comment: well one is i have to use that language and second it is a company pc